# How to call a dataframe to add a column, while not using its name?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I work on environmental data with fish. I have two dataframes one full `data` and the other is a subset (ie. one season) `data.summer`. Both dataframes have exact same columns. I would like to calculate couple of things (growth rate, condition, etc.) for each fish (every row) in the full data and only in summer. I'm working on a loop `for`, where I want the variable `j` to be the dataframe name. I tried to use `get()` function, however it only works to read the data, but I cannot change the dataframe with it, I cannot add new column. Is there any other function I could use in the loop to call the dataframe to add a new column, while not using dataframe name?

Here is what I've got and tried:

```
data <- data.frame(var1 = c(3, 5, 5, 6, 6),  # Example data.frame
                   var2 = c(4, 2, 2, 1, 8),
                   season = c("summer", "summer", "winter", "summer", "winter"))
data$season = as.factor(data$season)
data.summer = data[which(data$season == "summer"),]

for (j in c("data", "data.summer")) {
  get(j)$var2
  get(j)$var3 = get(j)$var1 / mean(get(j)$var2)
}
```

```
>   get(j)$var2
[1] 4 2 2 1 8
>   get(j)$var3 = get(j)$var1 / mean(get(j)$var2)
Error in get(j)$var3 = get(j)$var1/mean(get(j)$var2) : 
  could not find function "get<-"
> get(j)$var1 / mean(get(j)$var2)
[1] 0.8823529 1.470588 1.470588 1.764706 1.764706
```

Answer (score 0):

I played with the data, and found a little "roundabout" solution: I simply created a copy of dataframe with `copy = get(j)` and worked in the loop with `copy`. Then at the end of the loop I used `if` loop to overwrite original dataframes with the new ones.
This is how it looks:

```
data <- data.frame(var1 = c(3, 5, 5, 6, 6),  # Example data.frame
                   var2 = c(4, 2, 2, 1, 8),
                   season = c("summer", "summer", "winter", "summer", "winter"))
data$season = as.factor(data$season)
data.summer = data[which(data$season == "summer"),]

for (j in c("data", "data.summer")) {
  copy = get(j)
  copy$var3 = copy$var1 / mean(copy$var2)

  if (j == "data") {
    data = copy
  } else { data.season = copy}

}
```